# Can I run a cable straight into a junction box?

Tags: junction

I have a junction box like the one shown in the picture below. Do I just run the cable straight in or do I have to use some conduit/coating? I am thinking that maybe if I run the cable straight in the cable insulation might be damaged from the pressure of the hole. [image]

Comment: What type of cabling are you talking about? What is this wire used for?

Comment: There are clamps designed to hold the cable in the hole. But what type will depend on the type of box and the type of cable.

Comment: What country is this installation in?

Answer (score 1):

Clamps are required to protect the cable from damage, I like raco brand insiders because they are quick and inexpensive, there are also 2 screw cable clamps that are commonly used to protect cables like T&B nc301 , these are easily found at plumbing and electric shops or big box stores.